# Python intersect two list with condition

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is this one-liner the best way (without error and most efficient) for merging (doing the intersection) of two lists only if a certain condition is met?

```
res = [val for val in list_1 if val in list_2 and condition[val] == True]
```

I.e.

```
list_1 = [2 4 6 8 10]
list_2 = [1 2 3 4 5 8 9]
condition = {2:True, 4:False, 6:False, 8:True, 10:True}
```

should return `res = [2 8]`. The dictionary `condition` always has the same keys as the elements in `list_1`.

How should I change my code if instead of two lists I had sets?

Finally, note that this is a very simplified case that I produced for a larger example that I cannot check visually. I would like to make sure my solution is valid in general and not only for the posted example.

Comment: You could always test your one-liner in the interpreter.  Also, the `== True` is [unidiomatic in Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).  You should just do: `if val in list_2 and condition[val]`.

Comment: @iCodez - This is a very simple case that I produced for a larger example that I cannot check visually. I would like to make sure it is valid in general and not only for the posted example.

Comment: Will break if val is not in the dictionary.

Comment: I would convert condition to a third list that holds only keys for which condition holds, and take an intersection of the three lists.

Comment: I don't know how large your "larger example" is, but this is going to be pretty inefficient if `list_2` is big enough, because you're checking each element of `list_1` against every element of `list_2`, one by one. Consider converting `list_2` to a set.

Comment: Or, even better, combine the above two by using, e.g., `set(list_2) & {k for k, v in condition.items() if v}` to pre-filter the values.

Comment: Also, what does "the intersection" mean if there are duplicate values? For example, if `list_1 = [2, 2, 2, 10]`, should you get just `[2]` because `2` only appears once in `list_2`, or should you get `[2, 2, 2]`? (And if duplicates either can't possibly arise or can't possibly matter, is there a reason you're using lists instead of sets in the first place?)

Comment: Or even `list(set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set([x for x in condition if condition[x]]))`

Comment: @abarnert - Thanks for all of your feedback. Probably I should have specified better in the question (just updated) that there cannot be duplicates. I will definitively convert the lists to sets since they have constant look-up time.

Comment: @ojy - Thanks for your response. Could you please explain me what is the difference between your solution and the one by @abarnert?

Comment: Well, my solution returns a complete answer. I just suggest to take an intersection of 3 sets.  No looping through the elements of the first list.

Comment: @ojy: You're still looping through the elements of the first list, you're just doing it in the `set` constructor (and again in the intersection operator). The significant difference here is that converting `list_1` to a set throws away the order of `list_1`. If that's acceptable, it may be worth doing to specifically signal the fact that order doesn't matter; if it's not acceptable, obviously don't do it.

Comment: @ojy: Also, why are you passing a list comprehension to the `set` constructor? Why not either use a set comprehension (as in my comment) or pass a generator expression to `set` (if you need 2.6 backward compatibility)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously valid for your test case.

However, it *isn't* valid if `val` isn't guaranteed to be in `condition`.

If that's a possibility, you should either put a `try:`/`except:` around the check (which would mean abstracting it out into an explicit loop statement or a separate function), or use `condition.get(val, False)` (assuming that you want to treat "not in `condition`" as falsey).

If that isn't a possibility, it's probably better to leave your code as-is; that way, if you get "impossible" data, you'll get an exception instead of an incorrect answer.

---

Meanwhile, `== True` comparisons are usually not idiomatic and not a good idea. As [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says:

> Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`.

Of course this is just a guideline; there are some cases where you explicitly want to make sure something is `True`, not just truthy, in which case you need to use `== True` or `is True` (the former accepts other numeric `1` values, the latter doesn't). But if you don't have any reason to do so, don't do it.

---

Also, you say, "this is a very simplified case that I produced for a larger example…" I don't know how large "larger" is, but your code will be pretty inefficient if `list_2` is big enough.

You're checking each element of list_1 against every element of list_2, one by one. So, if there are, say, 1000 entries in each list, that's 1000000 comparisons.

If you instead convert `list_2` to a set, you're only doing a set lookup for each element of list 1, so it's only 1000 hashes and 1000 comparisons, not 1000000 comparisons.

You could write that as:

```
set_2 = set(list_2)
res = [val for val in list_1 if val in set_2 and condition[val]]
```

---

You can also simplify things in various ways. These won't affect performance, but could improve readability and semantic reasonability. In particular, as ojy says, you can easily combine the two conditions into one by using a set intersection, a set comprehension, or both. For example:

```
set_2 = set(list_2) & {k for k, v in condition.items() if v}
res = [val for val in list_1 if val in set_2]
```

You can take this even further by using another set intersection:

```
res = set(list_1) & set(list_2) & {k for k, v in condition.items() if v}
```

However, this one changes the semantics: it discards any duplicate values in `list_1`, and also throws away the order. If those are acceptable, it's probably a good idea to do it, just to make it obvious that duplicates are impossible and order is irrelevant. If not, obviously don't do this.

---

Finally, it's worth asking whether you're using the wrong data structures in the first place. Can you build `list_2` as a set instead of a list in the first place? Or `list_1`? Can you build `conditions` as a set of true keys instead of a dict mapping to True and False?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using **built-in** method **set**.
This is compatible in both current stable versions of Python - Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

```
list_1 = [2 4 6 8 10]
list_2 = [1 2 3 4 5 8 9]
condition = {2:True, 4:False, 6:False, 8:True, 10:True}

true_values = [x for x in condition.keys() if condition[x]] #Obtains keys having only 'True' value.

print set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set(true_values) #Give unique common value from these three lists.
```

If you want your set in ascending order, you can use "sorted" function replacing the last line as

```
print sorted(set(list_1) & set(list_2) & set(true_values)) #Will give [2, 8]
```

Comment: Why use `sets.Set`? It's deprecated in 2.6 and gone in 3.x. Unless you need backward compatibility with ancient versions of Python (but not _too_ ancient, because 2.3 didn't have `sorted`, 2.2 didn't have `sets`, and 1.5 didn't have list comprehensions…) more than you need future compatibility, this is silly.

Comment: With your advice, I have made it compatible with both stable versions of Python :). However, there are "very few" people using old versions of Python. Majority is considered.